# Python Data Scrape - Form Authentication Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, forms-authentication

Below is some code that I have been trying to use to log in to the cook's illustrated website (https://www.cooksillustrated.com/sign_in).

I start a session, get the authentication token and a hidden encoding field, and then pass the "name" and "value" of the email and password fields (found by inspecting the elements in chrome). The form doesn't seem to contain any other elements; however, the post method doesn't log me in.

I noticed that all of the CSRF tokens ended in "==", so I tried removing them. But it didn't work.

I also tried modifying the post to use the "id" field of the form inputs instead of the "name" (just a shot in the dark, really...name seems like it should work from what I've seen in other examples).

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

```
import requests, lxml.html
s = requests.session()

# go to the login page and get its text
login = s.get('https://www.cooksillustrated.com/sign_in')
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)

# find the hidden fields names and values; store in a dictionary
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib['name']: x.attrib['value'] for x in hidden_inputs}
print(form)

# I noticed that they all ended in two = signs, so I tried taking that off
# form['authenticity_token'] = form['authenticity_token'][:-2]

# this adds to the form payload the two named fields for user name and     password
# found using the "inspect elements" on the login screen
form['user[email]'] = 'my_email'
form['user[password]'] = 'my_pw'

# this uses "id" instead of "name" from the input fields
#form['user_email'] = 'my_email'
#form['user_password'] = 'my_pw'

response = s.post('https://www.cooksillustrated.com/sign_in', data=form)
print(form)

# trying to see if it worked - but the response URL is login again instead of main page
# and it can't find my name
# responses are okay, but I think that just means it posted the form
print(response.url)
print('Christopher' in response.text)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.ok)
```

Comment: The "==" at the end of CSRF token is [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_Padding) as it's a Base64 string.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean it needs to be decoded or removed? Or should it pass "as is"?

Comment: CSRF stands for **C**ross-**S**ite **R**equest **F**orgery, a type of attack when a malicious site, email, program, etc. causes a user's browser to perform an unwanted action. The token is a way of protecting against this. Needs to be passed as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the POST request URL should be `https://www.cooksillustrated.com/sessions`, and if you capture all traffic while logging in, you'll find out the actual POST request made to the server:

```
POST /sessions HTTP/1.1
Host: www.cooksillustrated.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 179
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://www.cooksillustrated.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://www.cooksillustrated.com/sign_in
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Uvku64N8V2dq8z%2BGerrqWNobn03Ydjvz8xqgOAvfBmvDM%2B71xJWl2DmRU4zbBE15gGVESmDKP2E16KIqBeAJ0g%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=demo&user%5Bpassword%5D=demodemo
```

Notice that the last line is encoded data for this request, there're 4 parameters which are `utf`, `authenticity_token`, `user[email]` and `user[password]`.

So in your case, `form` should include all of them:

```
form = {'user[email]': 'my_email', 
        'user[password]': 'my_pw', 
        'utf': '&#x2713;', 
        'authenticity_token': 'xxxxxx' # make sure you don't ignore '=='
}
```

Also, you might want to add some headers to appear as coming from Chrome (or whatever browser you like), since the default header of `request` is `python-requests/2.13.0` and some websites don't like traffic from "bots":

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', 
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
           ... # more
}
```

Now we're ready to make the POST request:

```
response = s.post('https://www.cooksillustrated.com/sessions', data=form, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing the post function to the /sessions URL worked perfectly. It didn't require me to change headers, but I will add them just to avoid issues. 


For anyone wondering where Shane's header and form info came from, in Chrome you can go to Inspect > Network > [Select the form name from left] > Headers. The "filter" box doesn't seem to work on the header text, but you can find the most recent actions relatively easily.